# Python: ttk: disable/enable a button

Tags: python, ttk

I want to change ttk.Button's state according to some internal logic. I create a button and associate a style with it:

```
cardBtnStyle = ttk.Style()
cardBtnStyle.configure('CB.TButton')
cardBtn = ttk.Button(top, text="Make SD card", style='CB.TButton', command = cardCreateCallBack).grid(column=1, row=5)
```

Following statement has no effect:

```
style.configure('CB.TButton', state='disabled')
```

But when I create a button like this, it is disabled:

```
cardBtn = ttk.Button(top, text="Make SD card", style='CB.TButton', state='disabled', command = cardCreateCallBack).grid(column=1, row=5)
```

How do I change ttk.Button state in Python?

OS: Ubuntu 13.10

Python: 2.7.5+

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The button state is not part of its style. You can use the [state()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ttk.html#ttk.Widget.state) method to modify it:

```
cardBtn.state(["disabled"])   # Disable the button.
cardBtn.state(["!disabled"])  # Enable the button.
```

Comment: I get following error: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1473, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 534, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "./viaVPN-Production.py", line 42, in state_thread
    cardBtn.state(["disabled"])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'state'

Comment: @yegorich, that error message means that `cardBtn` is set to `None`. However, the code in your question assigns an instance of `ttk.Button` to it, so it should not be the case. Double-check that you're invoking `state()` after initializing the button instance.

Comment: I think I've found the problem: you can't create an object, if you place it at once (`.grid()` or `.pack()`). It must be done in two stages: create an object and then place it. This way you can use its handle.