# How to (re)enable tkinter ttk Scale widget after it has been disabled?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, ttk, tkinter-scale

I'm trying to reenable my `Scale` widget in Python tkinter after disabling it but it doesn't work. I tried multiple options but none are working.

```
s.state(["normal"]);
s.configure(state='normal');
```

The error that I'm getting is saying:

> ```
> _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-state"
> ```

Comment: Are you using a `tkinter.Scale` or a `ttk.Scale`?

Comment: Im using `ttk.Scale`.

Comment: I think that you should rephrase your question a little to `How to enable/disable ttk widget`, since solution applies to all of them. I found nearly a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673257/python-ttk-disable-enable-a-button) of your question, because someone was curious only about a button.

Comment: Okay, I just changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use `ttk` widget, the state that you needed to reenable your widget is `!disabled`.

According to [ttk states](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_widget.htm#M21):

> A state specification or stateSpec is a list of state names, optionally prefixed with an exclamation point (!) indicating that the bit is off.

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk


root = tk.Tk()

scale = ttk.Scale(root)
scale.pack()

#   disable scale
scale.state(['disabled'])
#   enable scale
scale.state(['!disabled'])

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Note that ttk and tkinter use a different set of states/state names. tkinter uses 'normal' is the default; 'disabled', or 'disable' makes it visible but not responsive/greyed out; and 'active' for the state seen when mouse hovers over... e.g., button turns blue with mac aqua theme.