# ttk.Button state change sometimes not working

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I've been building a program and came across a weird response when trying to change state of `ttk.Button()`. So far everything was smooth but then I came across some problems and found out that `state` option is actually not an option when creating a `ttk.Button()`. I do know how to change it using Style() and so on. Yet, when creating a `ttk.Entry()` object, it accepts state as an option and sets it accordingly. The weird response is when you try to change the state with another button.

This is a code, where `state` has been defined as `disabled` - this shows that the option has been accepted. But the function does not work. At least for me.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

def change_state():
    if button1['state'] == 'disabled':
        button1['state'] = 'normal'
    elif button1['state'] == 'normal':
        button1['state'] = 'disabled'

button1 = ttk.Button(root, state='disabled', text='test')
button1.pack()

button2 = ttk.Button(root, text='change state', command=change_state)
button2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Here I did some random amendment and added another line in the function.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

def change_state():
    print(button1['state'])
    if button1['state'] == 'disabled':
        button1['state'] = 'normal'
    elif button1['state'] == 'normal':
        button1['state'] = 'disabled'

button1 = ttk.Button(root, state='disabled', text='test')
button1.pack()

button2 = ttk.Button(root, text='change state', command=change_state)
button2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

And now out of nowhere, this function works. Although nothing should work in the first place, because `state` is not accepted as an option and hence is not configurable in the standard way. Anyone else has the same response running these two versions. And could anyone explain what is going on? I think the same applies to `ttk.Entry()` as well, and possibly others.

Comment: The `state` option of `ttk.Button` is for backwards compatibility only, and is write-only - it can't be fully functional, because ttk has an incompatible notion of what widget state is, consisting of about ten different flags that can take independent values.  I think your `change_state()` would have worked, if you had used a separate variable to track the state rather than trying to read it back from the Button.  The proper way to do this with ttk is to use the `.state()` and `.instate()` methods - sorry, don't have an example of their usage handy.

Comment: For me (in Linux) none of the two versions works, the button stays disabled.

Comment: Here is a short example how to set the state with `.state()`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673257/python-ttk-disable-enable-a-button . But how do you actually check for the state and make an if/else logic?

Answer (score 2):

The value return by `button[state]` is not a python `str` so by doing `button1['state'] == 'disabled'` is always going to be false. It can be further checked with `type(button1['state'])` which returns `<class '_tkinter.Tcl_Obj'>`.

```py
def change_state():
    if str(button1['state']) == 'disabled':
        button1['state'] = 'normal'
    elif str(button1['state']) == 'normal':
        button1['state'] = 'disabled'
```